# Qt static builds take a very long time on a virtual machine(win7 32 bit)

Tags: c++, qt

Building a "shared build" of a Qt app (a build where the exe looks for Qt dlls externally and is small in size) takes very quickly (<5 minutes)

A "static build" (links against built static Qt apps, doesn't require dlls later on) takes about 30 minutes for a release build and 90 minutes for a debug build.

Is this completely unavoidable?

It waits a long time in the link phase I believe. Is there any way to speed it up? Is it trying to link to every possible Qt library or what?

In the `QT` flag I have only added `core`, `network` and `gui`. It shouldn't take over a hour to link, why is this happening?

I'm using `QtCreator` with `MinGW` on `Windows 7` on a virtual machine.

**EDIT**:

It seems that it has to do with adding debug symbols. When I add debug symbols to a release build, I get a 90 minute build time too.

Comment: it takes 5 minutes to build it normally? that's too much, what is your system?

Comment: @headsvk well, llittle ess than 5 minutes actually, it's Windows 7, 32 bit, but the difference with static build is mind-bogging

Comment: Yep, 5 minutes is ridiculously much, maybe you meant five seconds.

Comment: Link time code generation is the most likely explanation for the difference, not to mention the fact that linking cannot really be multi-threaded. But a link time of 90 minutes is still *way* too long.

Comment: Well it's a project of around 40 source files(and 40 headers), I have reduced includes as much as I can

Comment: what's your CPU and RAM? I'm curious

Comment: oh, sorry I forgot an important fact - it's on a virtual machine, however I have set it to have 4gb RAM and 100% execution cap on 1 CPU (as you said linking can't be multi-threaded anyway)

Comment: I would change the title to mention the virtual machine, any build cannot take so long normally

Comment: ok I changed description

Comment: Reading the comments thread at the link here will probably be helpful:  http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/03/27/speeding-up-visual-c-qt-builds/   (TL/DR:  MSVC's link-time optimization's time-to-completion is proportional to the amount of code you're statically linking in, and if you're statically linking in the Qt libraries, you're linking in *a lot* of code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Building a "shared build" of a Qt app (a build where the exe looks for
>   Qt dlls externally and is small in size) takes very quickly (<5
>   minutes)
>
> A "static build" (links against built static Qt apps, doesn't require
>   dlls later on) takes about 30 minutes for a release build and 90
>   minutes for a debug build.
>
> Is this completely unavoidable?

Generally speaking using VM implies using less CPU "heads". Make sure that your VM uses an adequate CPU resource then. And the "static" build time suggest you are probably building more than just an app but Qt framework static itself.

Also do you have prebuilt static Qt to use over and over? Or, you rebuilt it for "static", make sure to check the article [Building Qt 5 from Git](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) out:

> Multicore building:
>
> To speed up building when using nmake, the compiler can be instructed
>   to use all available CPU cores in one of the following ways:
>
> - Pass the option -MP to Qt's configure
> - Set the environment variable CL (specifying Visual Studio compiler options) to /MP (On the command line: set CL=/MP)
> - Use the tool jom instead of nmake. (Using jom instead of nmake reduces compile time quite a bit)

If it is only about building the app code and not the Qt itself, just mind the CPU heads you've allocated for VM and choose jom vs. nmake as long as it parallelizes the compiler execution by default.